# Document listener exhibiting unusual behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button with an onClick function that increments a state variable. I am trying to add an event listener such that when the user presses the enter key, it follows this exact same behaviour. However, it can be observed that when the user presses the enter key, it appears to call the function multiple times, instead of just once. How can I fix this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-gould-bpr7j

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [value, updateValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", e => handleKeyPress(e));
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(value);
    updateValue(oldVal => (oldVal + 1) % 2);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      onSubmit();
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={() => onSubmit()}>Click me</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In this case it's fairly clear what's wrong just from the code provide (nice one!), but generally if you can do your runnable [mcve] **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), that's better than off-site links. It's really easy to leave out something essential to making your question clear and complete if you use off-site links. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I've gone ahead and done the above for you. I've also updated my answer to show two ways to fix the problem I can observe. I never see the "multiple times" behavior in the snippet, just stale data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `useEffect` only ever sees the **first** version of `handleKeyPress`, which only ever sees the **first** version of `onSubmit`, which only ever sees the **first** version of `value`. In contrast, your button has the then-current version of `onSubmit` attached to its click handler, so it sees the current value of `value`, not the stale one.

Since `onSubmit` uses state information (`value`), and `handleKeyPress` uses `onSubmit`, one solution would be to add `handleKeyPress` as a dependency to your `useEffect` code and use a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) cleanup callback to update the `handleKeyPress` being used:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress); // No need for the arrow function here, and...
  return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress); // ...not using one simplifies this
  };
}, [handleKeyPress]);
```

You also need to move it to below where you create the function:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [value, updateValue] = useState(0);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(value);
    updateValue(oldVal => (oldVal + 1) % 2);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      onSubmit();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress); // No need for the arrow function here, and...
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress); // ...not using one simplifies this
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);

  return <button onClick={() => onSubmit()}>Click me</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**But** you can make `onSubmit` not rely on state information at all by moving the `console.log` out of it and into the state setter callback:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [value, updateValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    updateValue(oldVal => {
      console.log(oldVal);
      return (oldVal + 1) % 2;
    });
  };

  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      onSubmit();
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={() => onSubmit()}>Click me</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Then it's okay that only the old version of `handleKeyPress` is hooked up. Note that you *still* want to remove it when the component unmounts.

Comment: I thought passing an empty array to usEffect means it is only called once. If that is not the case, what does passing an empty array do?

Comment: Also, the value is no longer being updated when I call my function by pressing Enter. Only when I click the button does the value update.

Comment: @Perplexityy - You're quite right, I misremembered `[]` vs. not supplying one. (I really should be able to get them straight!) I've fixed the answer, but it also may not be an answer, it depends on what's going on with your specific situation. So if you could please do that on-site MCVE, that would help people answer your question.

Comment: @Perplexityy - There's also the issue that `useEffect` uses only the first version of `handleKeyPress`.